# CPU emulation in haskell, functional data structures, and maybe zippers?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

Well, not exactly. I have more of a functional data structures question.

Say I want to model the execution of a CPU. I have some set of instructions that mutate the CPU state (say it's a stack based cpu. Only jumps have operands... or whatever), some list of instructions that makes up the program, and labels. Jumps are done by reference to some label, not some offset. How do I represent this?

If I have a program that looks like `[Label "foo", Add, Add, Mult, Label "bar", Jnz "foo"]`, by the time I hit `Jnz "foo"`, I need to search backwards and forwards for the label "foo" to continue execution. That seems a bit silly. I think I should be able to have a better data structure that allows **quick jumps to labels**. Now, arbitrarily I'll say that I don't want to store offsets. Say the CPU allows self-modifying code or something like that. How should I patch up the code while making sure the references still point to a current version of the code?

I like the idea of Zippers. **I just don't know if the idea of making a zipper jump to a predefined location in O(1) time makes sense**

Answer (score 2):

An answer (but I'm not sure it is what you want) is to do what LLVM does and store code as `BasicBlock`s.  In this system each block is a pieces of code that can only be entered from the beginning. The last instruction *must* be a jump to another block. Then your labels, instead of being in the list of instructions, are attached to basic blocks.  A program might look like:

```
newtype Lable = [Char]
data Code = Data.Map Label [Instruction]
```

When you hit a jump instruction you simply `lookup` its block in the Map and keep going.

This has some real advantages if your goal is to optimize code (again the reason LLVM uses it), but it does break the pattern of simply representing your code as a list of instructions.

On the other hand, I cannot think of any CPU or computing model where labels are included in the program code.  In assembly they are just a convenient way of describing the fixed offset of the next line of code. they do not end up in the output, and if the code is modifiable at runtime the `jmp` instructions need to be modified as well.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like

```
import Data.Map as M
data Code = Code { instructions :: [Instruction], labels :: M.Map String [Instruction] }
```

where the values of the labels map are shared with the instructions list. You can keep the labels in the instruction stream and do something like

```
mkCode is = Code is (scan is)
              where scan [] = M.empty
                    scan (Label l:js) = M.insert l js (scan js)
                    scan (_:js) = (scan js)
```

to build a proper Code value.

Note that `Data.Map` implements binary search trees. If you want a hash table there's `Data.Hashtable`.

Comment: So then how do I modify the code while keeping references in tact?

Comment: Oh I missed the part about self-modifying code. That does make it a bit trickier. I'll think about it and update the answer.